# Expression implicity coerced from "error?" to Any

Tags: swift, swift3, error-handling

I have this error:

> Expression implicity coerced from "Error?" to Any

and I am not sure what it means, hoping to find help.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data,response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else {
        if let urlContent = data {
            do {
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                print(jsonResult)
            } catch {
                print("JSON Processing Failed")
            }
        }
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: Try it as `print(error as Any)`

Answer (score 1):

Check this line:

```
print(error)
```

You are printing an **optional value**. You should unwrap it with `if let`.

```
if let error = error {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: @JeremyP You are absolutely right, it's cleaner. Edited my answer.

Comment: For something like I think `guard error == nil else { print(error); return }`n is a better statement of intent. It does away with the else clause and keeps the main body of the closure (the happy path as it's sometimes called) closer to the left and more readable.

Comment: @Abizem I would also do that, but if you want to do something else after the "sad path", it's better this way.

Comment: @Abizern In general, `if let` is cleaner and reflects the structure of the program better since the indentation doesn't lie. However, in this case, it's handling an error condition, so I would probably use a `guard` statement.

Comment: No, on second thoughts, the `if` is better in this case because you don't need a `return` and you don't need to do a force unwrap.

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies. Btw it seems to work with just `print(error!)`. Not sure if its entirely correct though since I'm force unwrapping it